# Error accessing Spinnaker UI: path not normalized

Tags: spinnaker

After port-mapping a new Spinnaker installation, I'm having trouble accessing its UI.

[image: Request errors]

This fails with an error like

```
spin-gate-7dbb96d964-5vs9z gate 2019-01-25 15:08:58.148 ERROR 1 --- [0.0-8084-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
spin-gate-7dbb96d964-5vs9z gate
spin-gate-7dbb96d964-5vs9z gate org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.
spin-gate-7dbb96d964-5vs9z gate     at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:248) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
spin-gate-7dbb96d964-5vs9z gate     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
spin-gate-7dbb96d964-5vs9z gate     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
...
```

on the server side.

Background: I've port-mapped its port, in order to access it:

```
export DECK_POD=$(kubectl get pods --namespace cd -l "cluster=spin-deck" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl port-forward --namespace cd $DECK_POD 8080:9000 >> /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to port-forward the Gate pod as well, since Deck needs to access it.

```
export DECK_POD=$(kubectl get pods --namespace cd -l "cluster=spin-deck" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
export GATE_POD=$(kubectl get pods --namespace cd -l "cluster=spin-gate" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl port-forward --namespace cd $DECK_POD 8080:9000 >> /dev/null &
kubectl port-forward --namespace cd $GATE_POD 8084:8084 >> /dev/null &
```